# How to model an object oriented design in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, data-modeling, object-oriented-analysis, object-oriented-database

Suppose we have three concepts as bellow:

Concept ( attribute1, attribute2, .. )

A ( a, b, c, d )

B ( a, b, c, d, e )

C ( a, b, c, d, f )

There are three options to model these three concepts in the database:

**1) To model them as they are**

Table { column1, column2, ... }

A { id, a, b, c, d }

B { id, a, b, c, d, e }

C { id, a, b, c, d, f }

***Con:*** There is data redundancy.

**2) Model all in one table**

A { id, object_type, a, b, c, d, e, f }

***Con:*** Some fields remain empty for some concepts.

**3) Use relation between tables**

A { parent_id, a, b, c, d }

B { id, parent_id, e }

C { id, parent_id, f }

***Con:*** Increase query complexity to join tables.

Which method would you use? Do you have other solutions? Do you think the third method has less performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly, your option 1 is the worst choice. The main problem here is that you need to duplicate all rows of `B` and `C` in `A`, thus creating a severe maintenance problem.

Your option 2 is called the ***Single Table Inheritance*** pattern,  which is recommended in cases where subtables do not have (m)any additional columns.

Your option 3 is called the ***Joined Tables Inheritance*** pattern where subtables (representing subclasses) are joined to their supertable via their primary key being also a foreign key referencing the supertable.

So, for the case of your abstract example, it seems that option 2 is the recommended approach, since your tables `B` and `C` have only one additional column.

Notice that according to the *Joined Tables Inheritance* approach, there is no need to add a primary key attribute (as you did with `id` in `B` and `C`). You just use the same primnary key as the supertable and make it also a foreign key referencing the supertable. So, in this approach, the schema would be

```
A { id PK, 
    a, b, c, d 
}
B { id PK REFERENCES A, 
    e 
}
C { id PK REFERENCES A, 
    f 
}
```

You can read more about this in the section [Subtyping and Inheritance with Database Tables](http://web-engineering.info/tech/JsFrontendApp/subtyping-tutorial.html#secInheritTbl) of my tutorial about developing front-end web applications with class hierarchies.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. And if A { id, a, b, c, d, e, f, g }

B { id, a, b, c, d, h, i, j, k }

C { id, a, b, c, d, l, m, n, o } Do you still think first option is the worst?

Comment: In this new example you do not really have A as a supertable of B and C, since the attributes e,f,g of A are not shared with B and C.

Comment: That is true. But you could make a table called Object { id, a, b, c, d } and use Joined Tables Inheritance for A, B, and C. I am wondering about the trade-of between the better efficiency of Joined Table Inheritance and better performance of first option (which I realized is called Concrete Table Inheritance)

Comment: I think that the 'Concrete Table Inheritance' pattern (the name is by Martin Fowler) only makes sense if you have a class hierarchy where (more or less) only the leaf classes are concrete classes and all others abstract. Otherwise you get a lot of duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Propel developers say, that option 2 "is the most efficient implementations from a SQL and query performance perspective, but is limited to a small number of inherited fields" http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/09-inheritance.html